# How can I construct an 8 x 1 multiplexer from an 4 x 1 multiplexer and 2 x 1 multiplexer?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

How to design an 8x1 MUX from 4x1 MUX and 2x1 MUX ?

Comment: IIRC the most you will be able to do is 5 to 1.

Comment: @Passerby, by cascading 2^n-to-1 is possible for n = 1, 2, ...

Comment: -1. Smells like homework and doesn't explain what has been tried.

Comment: Smells like a homework problem.  Effort to solve not demonstrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe9LSA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: IMO questions that are obviously homework should not be answered in a way that provides the full answer. Maybe it should be a -1 for that reason, but it feels a bit strange to -1 an answer that is otherwise 100% correct.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen, I also thought bout only hinting at the answer, but I don't think the quality of my answers should suffer because a question looks like homework. What if he needs the solution to save a bus of kids from terrorists? Its for the kids, Wouter. Also this a bit of a classic EE interview/study/homework question, and one that needs no explanation. Once you see the answer you understand how MUX cascading works.

Comment: I teach this type of stuff myself, and every time a student looks up an answer instead of constructing it for him self an opportunity for learning is lost. (And one day I might travel in an airplane for which he programmed the autopilot.) Hence I disagree with your first sentence: when the question is obviously homework, I'd rather see a 'directional' answer than a final solution. But maybe that's against the spirit of this site. Might make a good meta discussion. (Note that I did not -1 your answer.)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen you are totally right and just to enhance that here's the same guy asking virtually the same question but about 2:1MUXES http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84325/how-to-design-an-2x4-decoder-from-1x2-demultiplexer Here's a chance to vent your downvote!!!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen right you are. Maybe providing the solution isn't in the best interest in the student. But that is what he asked for and I answered the question as asked, in good faith. In the end, it is his responsibility to not cheat, not ours. It is his responsibility to say it is homework, and he doesn't want a full solution. I actually think homework questions are usually the best questions on the site, so I think the stigma against them is unfortunate. Here's the discussion on SO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions